# When a user edits his mod deleted post, the moderator should be notified

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, global-inbox

When a moderator handles a flag, it is hard to find out later what flags you've handled and whether anything happened to the posts afterwards. While moderating a didn't post on [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/41029/23) I noticed a mod deleted answer which got edited a day later with basically a misguided comment regarding the deletion, and so I wasn't surprised to notice that the moderator or the community never really had a chance to notice.

It'd be nice if, in the once in a blue moon scenario where a 1 rep user comes back to the site, logs back into his original account, notices the comment reply and engages with it, we could be given the chance to notice and perhaps explain. (At 1 rep, flagging (?), editing your post and asking a question in the wrong place are your only in-site resorts, with editing perhaps being the most obvious approach.)

I'm proposing this at first as a mod power mainly for simplicity - and our ability to comment on flagged posts - but something of the sort would ideally also work for 10k-deleted posts.

Comment: If the post is deleted, do we really care what content is in it?

Comment: @RobertHarvey The user might've fixed the issue with the post.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Well, you didn't really say that in your question.  People defacing their own deleted posts, or attempting to engage in conversation with others using them, is of no interest to me.

Comment: In the meantime, I believe any user with 10k+ reputation can see deleted posts (and their revision history), so they should still be able to flag the question for moderator attention if needed. (EDIT: And users can always see their own deleted posts, I think.)